# Execute change method on select hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list (menu) with values ​​when the user clicks to execute a function that changes the value of a select is hidden. This works fine, but does not display the information to be displayed by selecting the correct option from the select itself.

```
<ul>
<li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>SELECCIONE</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a id="S0001" href='#'><span>AUTO NUEVO</span></a>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a id="S0002" href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

```
<script>
 $("#S0001").click(function(){
     $("#proyecto").val('S0001');
      $("#proyecto").change.val();        
      });
</script>
```

This is the hidden select to have all the functionality

```
<div id="styledselect"><select name="proyecto" id="proyecto">
 <option value='S0001'>AUTO NUEVO</option>
 <option value='S0002'>CELEBRACIONES</option>
</select></div>
```

For this to work correctly, once I changed the value of the select should run the change event itself and charge the correct information.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"does not display the information to be displayed by selecting the correct option from the select itself"* ?? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I used to have a select combo (select that is now hidden)than to choose was on a change event which calls a web service to display information.

I need to make a dropdown menu to select your option to change the hidden select for it to load the web service information. 

As you can see in the code I post, I get select change the value, but this does not make the change() select hidden action, therefore,I can't display the web service information.

Comment: All information from the web service is scheduled to be displayed according to the hidden select combo and I can't change it because it is a very large javascript library.

Comment: For hitting the web service, have you binded the change event of hidden select using jQuery or pure js?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the probloem is resolved by tymeJV, I changed one word (change())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `change` event:

```
$("#proyecto").change()
```

Note: this will run the defined `change` handler, not the native functionality